# How to set excel cell time format in PhpSpreadsheet

Tags: php, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice

How to set excel cell time format in PhpSpreadsheet?

=> I have set perticular time format in cell. but, i coudn't find.

**Note**: check my screenshot for more details

[image]

Comment: Hate to be that guy, but it's in the docs: https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/#write-a-date-or-time-into-a-cell

Comment: New link seems to be needed:
https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#write-a-date-or-time-into-a-cell

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to look in [NumberFormat](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/develop/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Style/NumberFormat.php) for the one you want, then apply it per [this section](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/topics/recipes/#number-formats).